# Name or Service not known - intermittent error in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a TimerTrigger which calls my own Azure Functions at a relatively high rate - a few times per second. It is not being stress tested. Every call takes just a 100ms and the purpose of the test is not a stress test.

This call to my own endpoint works about 9999 times out of 10000 but just once in a while I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known (app.mycustomdomain.com:443)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I replaced my actual domain with "app.mycustomdomain.com" in the error message above. It is a custom domain set up to point to the Azure Function App using CNAME.

The Function App does not detect any downtime in the Azure Portal and I have Application Insights enabled and do not see any errors. So I assume the issue is somehow on the callers side and the call never actually happens.

What does this error indicate? And how can I alleviate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question - alleviating the problem, one option would certainly be to build in retry using a library like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). High level you create a policy, e.g. for a simple [retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry):

```
var myPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
  .Retry(3);
```

This would retry 3 times, to use the policy you can call a sync or async version of Execute:

```
await myPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
     //do stuff that might fail up to three times
});
```

[More complete samples are available](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples)

This library has lots of support for other approaches, e.g. with delays, exponential delays, etc.

Comment: Thank you and then I guess the implied answer to the first question is to expect that this sort of random thing happens from time to time. I am just burdened by the knowledge that there is a reason for everything.

Comment: It’s always safe to assume these random things happen, that’s not to say someone else couldn’t give you the reason for the original issue. I hope Polly can alleviate some of your burden! :)

Comment: Thank you. Got it implemented with some difficulty and it seems to have alleviated it somewhat.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for me, but that's a new question. I am probably doing it wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557887/polly-does-not-timeout